# JavaScript - get content of popup window

Tags: javascript, popup, window

I'm trying to read the contents of a document that is loaded via `window.open`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <button onclick="openWin()">Open "newWindow" and read its content</button>

        <script>
            var myWindow;

            function openWin() {
                myWindow = window.open("http://www.google.com/", 
                    "myWindow", "width=400, height=400");

                myWindow.opener.document.write(myWindow.document.body.innerHTML);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I read the contents of a document after loading it via `window.open`?
I've tried this with `setTimeout` function but it didn't work.
This is working :

```
myWindow.opener.document.write("Done!!");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that if the document you're opening in a new window is from a different domain (for example, `yoursite.com` opening a new window that loads `google.com`). This is a security restriction known as *same-origin policy*. More information: [Same-origin policy (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Hope this clarifies things a bit for you.

Answer (score 0):

It can sometimes pay to try a few things.

My isp recently added a time stamp to their login form which prevented me using my local post form with preloaded name and password.

I looked for ways of downloading their login page and copying the time stamp to my local form. This would have been easy with almost any script except JavaScript.

Frames failed as they use the X-Frame-Option set to 'Deny'.

To my surprise I was able to copy the time stamp to my local form from a pop-up window containing their form. This now works well. The only slight imperfection was having to use a fixed timeout rather than detecting pop-up page fully loaded.

Here is the disguised full solution:

```
<html>
<head>
<base href='https://www.isp.net'>
<title>isp</title>
</head>
<body onload="w=window.open('login'); setTimeout('document.f.time-stamp.value=w.document.forms[0].time-stamp.value; document.f.submit(); w.close()',2000)">
<form name=f action='login' method=post>
<input type=hidden name='user-name' value='my-name'>
<input type=hidden name='password' value='my-password'>
<input type=hidden name='time-stamp' value=''>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```